# Repeatable Code generation

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, editor, code-generation

It is awfully often required to write repeatable pieces of code.

Consider the following example from `Java` (although, it may not be the best example, but I hope you get the general idea...)

`String X = rs.getString("X");`

Where `X` will have values: `'name'`,`'surname'` ... and `20`-`30` other values.

(Another example would be an `HTML` code and any other code - you need to create for `X`)

The end result should be:

```
String name=rs.getString("name");
String surname=rs.getString("surname");
....

String whatever = rs.getString("whatever");
```

Here is another example with  `html` table and some `scriplets`, in this case string to replicate would be `<th>X</th>` and `<td><%=myBean.getX()%></td>` the end result would be:

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>surname</th> 
    <th>..</th>
    <th>whatever</th>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td><%=myBean.getName()%></td>
    <td><%=myBean.getSurname()%></td> 
    <td>..</td>
    <td><%=myBean.getWhatever()%></td> 
  </tr>
</table>
```

So, apart form copy-pasting the above for `30` times and then editing, the the only 'clever' way I found to deal with this is to use `python`, `jinja2` library and write a small code generator.

But, in order to do that I had to install `python`, install the library, create a `template`, create a custom `script` to read values from a `text file` and then generate code for the values read.

I was wondering is there any easier way to achieve the above?

Any editor or plugin to support code generation?

I know that IDEs such as Netbeans, Eclipse can generate some code - like getters and setters ... etc, but it is not enough...

In a nutshell, 
I want to regenerate some lines of code by altering only specific parts ... The question is how to achieve that easily? (I know the hard way to do this) ..I am seeking for ideas...

Comment: Be more specific, what is the question?

Comment: Store all X values in a List or Array, store all values in a Map<String, String>

Comment: There are libraries that handle these things in safer ways instead of resorting to code generation. ORM mappers for database operations, other tools for other things.

Comment: @Justas seem to me that I am going to a lot of trouble to achieve something relatively simple... I want to regenerate the lines of code by altering only specific parts ... The question is how to achieve that ..I am   seeking for ideas...

Comment: Code generation is the worst idea for things like these.

Comment: @Kayaman And how would you avoid that? I mean it is not just  java code it is also html etc (see edited version of question). Also there are times (like writing a web service client for example) when you got an object with tons of getters and setter - and you have no other choice but to use them in your code ... do same thing over and over with different setter or getter each time ...

Comment: @Plirkee, I'm still not sure what you are trying to solve, but I assume it is a `ResultSet` you are working with. See my answer for more details if that's the case.

Comment: With the proper tools and libraries. You think you're the first one who thought "well I don't want to keep writing these all over again"? Code generation is used often with web services, but even then you don't need to write the tools yourself. Object mappers can map database rows into domain objects, so you just need to write the domain classes. Etc. etc. etc. You've discovered a hammer (code generation), and you want to hammer everything, whether it's a nail, a screw or a squirrel. If you have a *specific* question, it could be answered better.

Comment: @Kayaman Haha.. Well `when you have a hammer everything looks like a nail` ;-) it true... Fair point, that there are no silver bullets ... and one could use Hibernate, Object mappers etc.. However, above (in OP) those where just examples..may be bad ones...I mean it doesn't have to do with database, not even with java (though I code in java) ..it could be `xml` or whatever. I was hoping some feature in editors or in IDEs that would allow for some command like 'write Z= X.getY()' 30 times by replacing Z,X,Y with given values.. based on answers I am guessing that there is no such thing...

Comment: Sure there are shortcuts, macros and such, but usually it's a design issue. At one point you're going to have to write some code, so if you use proper tools and write smart code, suddenly you realize that you don't really need to generate hundreds of lines. Generated code is also usually harder to maintain, so it's smart to avoid it if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably I am looking for something that does not exist.

So, I'll just post my '*hard way*' of achieving, what I have described in my question (in hope that this would be useful for somebody - sometime).

Here I will preset a small code generator I am using to generate java, html, jsp, xsd and other codes.

I am using [Python27](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7/) and [Jinja2-2.7.2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Jinja2/2.7.2)

My Files:

**InputData.txt**

```
:This is field list
field1:field1 description
field2:field2 description
field3:field3 description
field4:field4 description
name:first name of the person 
surname:last name of the person
whatever:whatever you need
```

**CodeGenerator.py**

```
import jinja2 
import codecs 
templateLoader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader( searchpath="." ) 
templateEnv    = jinja2.Environment( loader=templateLoader )
TEMPLATE_FILE  = "CodeGenerator.jinja" 
template       = templateEnv.get_template( TEMPLATE_FILE )
COLUMNS        = [tuple(line.split(':')) for line in codecs.open( "InputData.txt", "r", "utf-8" )]
COLUMNS        = map(lambda s: (s[0],(s[0].strip().title(),s[1].strip())), COLUMNS)
#title() copy of the string in which first characters of all the words are capitalized.
#strip()  copy of the string, all chars have been stripped from the beginning and the end
#lambda s --> (field1,(Field1,field1 description))
#ignore the first line 
COLUMNS.pop(0)
#add variables to work with 
templateVars = { "table" : "MyTableName",
                 "description" : "A simple code generator",
                 "columns" : COLUMNS
               }

outputText = template.render( templateVars ) 
f = open('Generated.txt', 'w') 
outputText = outputText.encode('utf-8')
f.write(outputText)
f.close() 
print outputText
```

**CodeGenerator.jinja**

```
//------------------model------------------------
//Generated code for model 
import java.io.Serializable;
public class {{table|capitalize}}_Model implements Serializable{
{%for columnName,columnTitle in columns%}
private String {{columnName|lower}};{%endfor%}

{% for columnName,columnTitle in columns %}
public void set{{columnName|capitalize}}(String {{columnName|lower}}){ 
  this.{{columnName|lower}}={{columnName|lower}};
}
public String get{{columnName|capitalize}}(){ 
  return this.{{columnName|lower}};
}
{% endfor %}
public {{table|capitalize}}_Model({% for columnName,columnTitle in columns %}String {{columnName|lower}}{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}{% endfor %}){
        {% for columnName,columnTitle in columns %}
  this.{{columnName|lower}}={{columnName|lower}}; {% endfor %}  
    }
public String toString(){

return {% for columnName,columnTitle in columns %}"{{columnName|lower}}:" + this.{{columnName|lower}}{% if not loop.last %}+{% endif %}{% endfor %};

}

}
//------------------model------------------------
//-----------------getStrings--------------------
{% for columnName,columnTitle in columns %}
 String {{columnName}}=rs.getString("{{columnName}}");
{% endfor %}
//----------------------------------------------
//------------------jsp example-----------------
{% for columnName,columnTitle in columns %}
<s:label  cssStyle ="margin-top:5px;color:blue;" value="{{columnTitle[1]}} :" id="{{columnName}}_label"/>
<s:textfield label="{{columnTitle[1]}}" name="myBean.{{columnName}}" />
{% endfor %}
//------------------jsp example-----------------
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with a lightweight code generator like Telosys :

- http://www.telosys.org/
- https://modeling-languages.com/telosys-tools-the-concept-of-lightweight-model-for-code-generation/

In your case Telosys-CLI with a DSL model is probably the right choice, you'll just have to create your specific templates in Velocity language ( http://velocity.apache.org/ )

Answer (score 0):

In such scenarios, the best thing you could do is to use a constant array together with a HashMap. The constant array will hold keynames for the hashmap whereas the hashmap will also hold the value for each one.

For instance:

```
String[] keys = {"name", "surname", "whatever" };
HashMap<String, String> elements = new HashMap<String, String>();
for (String key : keys)
{
    elements.put(key, rs.getString(key));
}
```

You just have to be careful that all the elements are from the same type. If they are not, you will have to either store them as Objects and then cast them.

EDIT: for using in a Scriptlet, a good idea would be:

```
<tr>
    <% for (String key : keys)
       {
    %>      
    <td><%= elements.get(key)%></td>
    <% } %>
</tr>
```

Answer (score -1):

In IntelliJ we have "Live Template" feature that you use to generate part of the code.

For example, when you type "sout" , IntelliJ suggests "System.out.println".

When you type "main" , Eclipse suggests "public static void main(String[] args)"

You can create something like that for pieces of code that are very commom.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your problem correctly, you have a `ResultSet` with a lot of columns. And you do not want to get them one by one.
It is possible to get all the columns from a `ResultSet` the following way:

```
ResultSetMetaData metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
for (int columnIndex = 1; columnIndex <= metaData.getColumnCount(); columnIndex++) {
    String columnName = metaData.getColumnName(columnIndex);
    String value = resultSet.getString(columnIndex);
}
```

Granted all the values will b e represented as strings in this example, but you can determine the type of the column also by using the same `metaData` object. Read more about it in the documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html